# How do I look for a byte sequence in a file?

Tags: c++, binary, mkv

I want to finde this arrange of bytes in a file :

[18][53][80][67] (HEX) 
00011000 1010011 10000000 1100111

The bytes represent Matroska Segment EBML ID  https://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html

I try to search in the file like this but with no results :

```
    is.seekg (0, is.end);
    int length = is.tellg();
    is.seekg (0, is.beg);

    char * buffer = new char [8];

    std::cout << "Reading " << length << " characters... ";
    // read data as a block:
      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
       std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
       is.read (buffer,sizeof(char));
       if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[0] == 1)         
           if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[1] == 8)     
               if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[3] == 10)
                   if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[4] == 3)
                       if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[5]==8)
                           if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[6]==0)
                               if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[7]==12)
                                   if((int)(unsigned  char)buffer[8]==7)
                                       std::cout<<"finish !!!!";
```

Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to remember that each hexadecimal number you show (e.g. `18`) is a *single byte*. That is you need to read and check *four* bytes instead of eight.

Secondly, you don't have to compare all bytes individually, you can read four bytes at a time and compare against an *array* of bytes containing the data you need to find:

```
// The data we need to find in the file
uint8_t data_to_find[] = { 0x18, 0x53, 0x80, 0x67 };

// The data from the file
uint8_t current_data[sizeof data_to_find];
```

Then read `sizeof current_data` bytes into the `current_data` array, and [compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp) against `data_to_find`:

```
if (std::memcmp(data_to_find, current_data, sizeof data_to_find) == 0)
{
    // Found the data
}
else
{
    // Didn't find the data
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you, you could use the search algorithm:

```
// ...
std::ifstream is( file_name, std::ios::binary );
if ( !is )
  return -1;
std::array<std::char, 4> ebml_id{ 0x18, 0x53, 0x80, 0x67 };
auto res = std::search( std::istream_iterator<char>( is ), std::istream_iterator<char>(), ebml_id.begin(), ebml_id.end() );
// ...
```